# NFC Drivers for KkMoon/FuRui NFC-PM5?

Tags: nfc

`nfc-list` & `nfc-scan-device` both says:

```
No NFC device found.
```

usb-devices lists it as:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 79 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1433 ProdID=4331 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Fu Rui 
S:  Product=NFCPM3
S:  SerialNumber=NFCPM3
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

The usb-storage part works in windows, and includes a software for using it in windows. But in Ubuntu it can't be mounted, running `fsck.vfat /dev/sdb` shows:

```
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Read 512 bytes at 0:Input/output error
```

Where can I find hint on how to use it?
It comes in 2 models, NFC-PM3 & NFC-PM5, where 5 supports more types/freqenses.
But googeling them just gives alot of ProxyMark PM3 devices :-(

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this...? It seems I have the same device and I cannot get it to work, either

Comment: By running a virtualbox with windows, I managed to log the USB-traffic to the HID-device, but I was unable to decode/understand the packages, also tried to deasemble the software, but isn't experienced enough to get any useful information from that either.

Comment: Sorry for persisting with this, but I'm frustrated with this nfc reader and that fact that I cannot make it work.  How did you get the "usb-devices lists it as"?  The /dev/sdb mount, I think, is only there to deliver the installation files (?).  Finally, did you actually make it work under linux? I'm not interested in their win app, I just want to extract the ids from the nfc cards and then do my thing with some python code.  Thanks!!!